# Linq query to remove the first entry with value > 0 in dictionary, when all subsequent values are zero

Tags: linq, dictionary

This is the dictionary,

```
Dictionary<string, uint> oSomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface1",3);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface2",0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface3",0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface4",0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface5",0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface6",0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface7",0);
```

Condition : When the first key's value in the `oSomeDictionary` is greater than 0 and the subsequent values are zero like above,remove the first key else do nothing.

Comment: There's no such concept as a "first" key within a logically dictionary - it's unordered. (There's "the first entry you happen to retrieve" but that can change if you add or remove elements.) Likewise there's no such concept as "subsequent" values. If you want insert-ordering, you want something like `List<T>`. Please give more context.

Comment: The word "query" means "ask a question", not "perform an action". A LINQ query can look through a dictionary and tell you the first entry it finds with some condition, but it can't remove anything.

Comment: Dictionary is static like above with no add or remove operations.The order of the keys are also same everytime the dictionary is created.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple code to solve your need but you should order your dictionary first as stated in the comment. Use this code carefully.

```
Dictionary<string, uint> oSomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface1", 3);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface2", 0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface3", 0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface4", 0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface5", 0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface6", 0);
oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface7", 0);

var ordered = oSomeDictionary.OrderBy(_ => _.Key);
if (ordered.First().Value > 0 && ordered.Skip(1).All(_ => _.Value == 0))
{
    oSomeDictionary.Remove(ordered.First().Key);
}
```

Comment: Got clues from your answer and modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

See the LINQ with the coditional stmt after that. If the deleteOrNot is true you can delete the first item. The deletion can not be done in LINQ. :)

```
      Dictionary<string, uint> oSomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

        oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface1", 3);
        oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface2", 0);
        oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface3", 0);
        oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface4", 0);
        oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface5", 0);
        oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface6", 0);
        oSomeDictionary.Add("Interface7", 0);
        bool deleteOrNot = ((from test1 in oSomeDictionary
                    where test1.Value > 0
                    select test1).Count() == 1) && (oSomeDictionary.First().Value > 0);
```